# Dynamically Displaying Record Count Per User

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table containing records created by different users on different dates. My goal is to get the date, users, count of records created by each user, and total count of records per date in [this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peDIM.png).

```
<?php 
    $q = "SELECT enroledby, enrolment_date, COUNT(enroledby) coun FROM sample_data GROUP BY enroledby";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$q);

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
    ?>                                       

                 <th><?php echo $row[0]; ?></th>

     <?php

                }



                ?>
```

The code above is dynamically echoing the users in table header as desired. How do I echo the date, count per user and total count as table data (td) like the above format ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an `AJAX` request to your query ?Because if you don't it'snot dynamic.

Comment: The table is echoed when a button is clicked.

Comment: Can you give an example from you tables ,what you want ,what you get and the expected values ?

Comment: $row[1] will store the date... $row[2] the count.